# My 768 laptop is getting 1050 resolution when I plug into an external and mirror the videos.

Tags: resolution, scaling

This seems crazy to me, but when I plug my laptop into a 22" HP monitor that supports 1050 mode, I can mirror my display on both screens and set the video settings of both at 1050.

This certainly looks like a higher resolution, but I can't be sure. When I unplug the external monitor - my internal ones blinks and goes back to 768. The display control panel shows the change and my screen shows the change.

I know this shouldn't be possible, and I posted elsewhere and was told that it's just windows 'glitching' and using scaling to try to interpret the change in resolution - that my monitor is not changing.

All specs about my laptop say it's limited at 768, but is it possible that it was down-spec'd? Maybe to sell a 'cheaper' version? If it is just scaling, is there anyway to get that scaling with someware instead of having to plug in an external?

One thing I just noticed, is I can blow up the pictures I made and you can count the lines in the icons. There are 24 lines in both versions. Just the second version, the icons are much smaller.

Thanks

Comment: A DFP’s native resolution isn’t necessarily the limit. It could always downscale the image.